# Ajuda com Jquery aparecer div

Tags: jquery

Boa tarde ,Preciso de ajuda referente ao jquery , abaixo um exemplo :

```html
<ul>
 <li><a href="#1">Conteudo1</a></li>
 <li><a href="#2">Conteudo2</a></li>
 <li><a href="#3">Conteudo3</a></li>

</ul>


<div class="teste" id="1">
 <p>Teste 1</p>
</div>

<div class="teste" id="2">
 <p>Teste 2</p>
</div>

<div class="teste" id="3">
 <p>Teste 3</p>
</div>


$(document).ready(function(){
 $('.teste').hide();

 
});
```

Como faço pra fazer aparecer somente a div que estiver referenciada no menu quando eu clicar ?

Comment: Esses href serão todos #1?

Comment: use o evento do jquery onClick

Comment: Desculpe , mais não sei como fazer , alguém poderia me ajudar , Sergio cada hfref e referente a um id , acabei de corrigir

Comment: @GabrielRodrigues na questão que você mencionou o usuário solicita a resposta em javascript puro. Aqui seria utilizando jQuery.

Comment: @JoaoPaulo não, a resposta votada como correta do Diego Vieira possui a resolução tanto para javascript quanto para jQuery.

Comment: @GabrielRodrigues além disso essa questão tem um contexto próprio. Não basta saber mostrar e esconder uma div.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tente assim:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("li a").click(function(){
        var id = $(this).attr("href");
        $(".teste").hide();
        $(id).show();
    });
});
```

Comment: Obrigado João , Salvou o meu dia , valeu mesmo ai cara

Comment: `+1` - se colocares esse `$(".teste")` em cache fora da função fica ainda melhor :)

Answer (score 2):

Faça assim:

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="#1">Conteudo1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#2">Conteudo2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#3">Conteudo3</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="teste" id="1">
  <p>Teste 1</p>
</div>

<div class="teste" id="2">
  <p>Teste 2</p>
</div>

<div class="teste" id="3">
  <p>Teste 3</p>
</div>


$(document).ready(function(){
    $('ul li a').click(function() {
       var div = $(this).attr("href");
       $(div).show().siblings('.teste').hide();
    })    
});
```

Veja um exemplo funcionando no jsfiddle [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yfcerky5/).

Comment: `$(div).show().siblings('.teste').hide();` ++

Answer (score 1):

Sei que já tens uma resposta aceite.

Mas aqui fica uma solução com JavaScript nativo:

```
function toggle(els, index) {
    return function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        for (var i = 0; i < els.length; i++) {
            els[i].style.display = i == index ? 'block' : 'none';
        }
    }
}

var lis = document.querySelectorAll('ul li a');
var testes = document.querySelectorAll('.teste');
for (var i = 0; i < lis.length; i++) {
    lis[i].addEventListener('click', toggle(testes, i));
}
```

#### jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/u6ykLt8u/

E uma versão em jQuery, com e sem ser preciso acesso ao ID:

Sem ter atênção o ID:

```
var $testes = $('.teste');
$('ul a').click(function(e) {
    var attr = $(this).attr('href').slice(1);
    $testes.each(function() {
        $(this).toggle(this.id == attr);
    });
});
```

Tendo atênção aos IDs:

```
var $testes = $('.teste');
$('ul a').click(function(e) {
    $testes.hide();
    $($(this).attr('href')).show();
});
```

Comment: Muito bom sua solução em javascript puro.

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul>
   <li><a href="#div1" id="1" class="link">Conteudo1</a></li>
   <li><a href="#div2" id="2" class="link">Conteudo2</a></li>
   <li><a href="#div3" id="3" class="link">Conteudo3</a></li>
</ul>


<div class="teste" id="div1">
    <p>Teste 1</p>
</div>

<div class="teste" id="div2">
    <p>Teste 2</p>
</div>

<div class="teste" id="div3">
    <p>Teste 3</p>
</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    //esconde todas as divs
    $('.teste').hide();

    //quando elemento com a class "link" for clicado
    $('.link').click(function(){
         //esconde todas as divs
         $('.teste').hide();
         //pega o id correspondente a div que quer mostrar
         var id = $(this).attr("id");
         //mostra a div correta
         $("#div"+id).show();
    });
});
</script>
```