# usar variável em .eq

Tags: jquery, html, css

Preciso colocar o valor de uma variável no método .eq, esse variável recebe um valor inteiro. Porém não funciona. Já tentei de vários jeitos e nada.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    i = 0;
    for(i = 0; i <= 30; i++)
    {
        $(".textoAberto").hide();
        $(".titlePrincipal").eq(i).click(function(){
            $(".textoAberto").eq(i).show();
        });
    };
    });
```

Comment: Acho que esta resposta também pode ser útil: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/128813/129